# How to transform a csv file having multiple delimiters using awk

Tags: shell, csv, awk

Below is a sample data. Please note this operation is required to be done on files with millions of records hence I need the optimal method. Essentially we are looking to update 2nd column with concatenation of first two characters from 4th column and excluding first 3 fields ('_' delimited) of 2nd column.

I have been trying using cut and reading the file line by line which is very time consuming. I need something with awk something like

```
awk -F, '{print $1","substr($4,1,2)"_"cut -f4-6 -d'_'($2)","$3","$4","$5","$6}'
```

Input Data:

```
234234234,123_33_3_11111_asdf_asadfas,01,06_1234,4325325432,2
234234234,123_11_2_234111_aadsvfcvxf_anfews,01,07_4444,423425432,2
234234234,123_33_3_11111_mlkvffdg_mlkfgufks,01,08_2342,436876532,2
234234234,123_33_3_11111_qewf_mkhsdf,01,09_68645,43234532,2
```

Output is required as:

```
234234234,06_11111_asdf_asadfas,01,06_1234,4325325432,2
234234234,07_234111_aadsvfcvxf_anfews,01,07_4444,423425432,2
234234234,08_11111_mlkvffdg_mlkfgufks,01,08_2342,436876532,2
234234234,09_11111_qewf_mkhsdf,01,09_68645,43234532,2
```

Comment: Please edit your questions with your attempts, and any details on what went wrong. The comment section is not the right place for such information.

Comment: Also, are you sure `awk` is going to be especially efficient for this compared to a scripted solution in something like Python?

Comment: I would prefer awk as we dont have python in the server where we need to transform this data. Please note the biggest file requiring this transform is 75 Gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk and `printf` for line re-formating

```
awk -F"[,_]" '{
    printf "%s,%s_%s_%s_%s,%s,%s_%s,%s,%s\n", $1,$9,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12
}' file
```

you get,

```
234234234,06_11111_asdf_asadfas,01,06_1234,4325325432,2
234234234,07_234111_aadsvfcvxf_anfews,01,07_4444,423425432,2
234234234,08_11111_mlkvffdg_mlkfgufks,01,08_2342,436876532,2
234234234,09_11111_qewf_mkhsdf,01,09_68645,43234532,2
```

Comment: This doesn't work for **general** CSV files. For example, if a field itself contains a comma - in CSV format, this would be written by enclosing it in quotes, i.e.  `....,"abc,def",...`, the awk program would also split on this comma. BTW, the title of your posting is misleading: You don't have multiple delimiters, but only one (the comma). Indeed, if you had multiple delimiters, this would not be considered CSV format anymore.

Comment: @user1934428 I agree with you, formats like `xml`, `json`, `html`, `csv`, etc., I recommend use specialized tools for parser